# Interfaces with protobuf-net and C#

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

Does anybody know what is the right way to set up a *ProtoContract* for an **Interface**?

I get the following exception "*The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated*" using only attributes.

Code used:

```cs
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Lesson5TestClass2 : ILesson5TestInteface1
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(1000, typeof(Lesson5TestClass2))]
    public interface ILesson5TestInteface1
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        string Name { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm able to deserialize only if I add the following setting:

```cs
  RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof (ILesson5TestInteface1), true)
      .AddSubType(50, typeof(Lesson5TestClass2));
```

I'd really love to configure this using only attributes.

I'm using protobuf-net r470 from NuGet.

BTW: This example is from a set of "Lessons through tests" showing how to do serialization with protobuf-net for my coworkers.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Why do you need interfaces for DTO´s?

Comment: @jgauffin: I'm just writting some code to understand protobuf-net capabilities. Lesson 5 is all about interfaces. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting; yes, it looks like something is up there. However, it *does* work when exposed as a member, i.e.

```
[ProtoContract]
class Wrapper
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ILesson5TestInteface1 Content { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Wrapper obj = new Wrapper
        {
            Content = new Lesson5TestClass2()
        }, clone;
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            clone = Serializer.Deserialize<Wrapper>(ms);
        }
        // here clone.Content *is* a Lesson5TestClass2 instance
    }
}
```

I will have to look to see what is up with interface support as the *root* object.

Comment: Yep, it seems it has a problem with the root object when you've never used the deserializer. I've written two tests one using the wrapper and one without the wrapper. If the test with the wrapper run first, the test without the wrapper passes. But if the test without the wrapper runs first, both tests will fail. :?

Comment: @graffic best thing is to log a bug, and I shall investigate. Very curious.

Comment: All right :) Friday evening here so perhaps you'll have to wait till monday (I'll do my best anyway). At the same time... I'll accept your answer as correct to close this question.

Comment: Marc, did this get fixed in v2? I am using r480 and getting the same issue.

Comment: @Eric v1 **never** supported interfaces. In v2 they still work as *members only*. I must fix that ...

Comment: @MarcGravell I was wondering did you fix interface support as the root object?

Comment: @BlackFrog no, because it would require a signature change; *what* interface did you want? An object can implement any number...

Comment: I think *root* interfaces can be supported quite easily, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution that worked for me is to let Protobuf know about the interface before serializing the actual instance.

```cs
var obj = new Lesson5TestClass2();
using var ms = new MemoryStream();

// vvv - Add this line
Serializer.PrepareSerializer<ILesson5TestInteface1>();

Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
ms.Position = 0;
var clone = Serializer.Deserialize<ILesson5TestInteface1>(ms);
```

I guess that call makes Protobuf serialize `Lesson5TestClass2` as instance of `ILesson5TestInteface1` which it doesn't do otherwise, because it has no chance to know about `ILesson5TestInteface1`.

This is probably what also happens if you use wrapper `class` as suggested by the other answer (then Protobuf knows about the interface because it's a type of a property it inspects before serialization).

> I'd really love to configure this using only attributes.

This solution is almost what you want, but still needs `PrepareSerializer` to be called once per interface (which is better than `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add` as that's once per implementation). However, you can easily create a helper method to call `PrepareSerializer` + `Serialize` combo every time (there will be no performance penalty as it's cached) and it should work just fine, no extra configuration needed.