# How to serialize an interface (protobuf-net)?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

want serialize SomeInterface that is contened SomeClass that declared in another dll. There is also the implementation of this interface.

```
public interface SomeInterface
{
     SomeClass Instance { get; }
}

public class BasicClass : SomeInterface
{
    public BasicClass(SomeClass instance)
    {
         Instance = instance;
    }

    public SomeClass Instance { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return Instance.ToDisplayString();
    }

}
```

If you use a *Surrogate*, you can not use *implicit operator* for *Interface*.

```
[ProtoContract]
class SomeInterfaceSurrogate
{ 
      [ProtoMember(1)] public int Id { get; set; }

      public static implicit operator SomeInterface(SomeInterfaceSurrogate value)
      {
            return value == null ? null : GetInstanceForId(int id);
      }

      public static implicit operator SomeInterfaceSurrogate(SomeInterface value)
      {   
            return value == null ? null : new SomeInterfaceSurrogate()
            {
                  Id = value.GetId()
            };
      }
}
```

What are the tools protobuf for such tasks?

Comment: Interfaces have no implementation ie no data or instance for that matter. There's nothing to serialize. Are you trying to solve a *different* problem and think that "serializing" interfaces is somehow the solution?

Comment: Your question is typically asked when someone is trying to give a class multiple roles. You probably have a class hierarchy in your business layer and try to transport those. Don't do that. Protect them and their structure and use DTOs instead. By doing so you also get a loose coupling between your tiers.

Comment: @jgauffin I don't understand what it means to use the structure of DTO. Where can I read about this, see some examples?

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: You should be able to use `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ISomeInterface), true).AddSubType(50, typeof(BasicClass));` in your *top level project on startup*, as is shown in [Interfaces with protobuf-net and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182188/interfaces-with-protobuf-net-and-c-sharp).