# protobuf-net deserialize with no access to base interface

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

There are dozens of posts about [ProtoInclude] but I don't have access to the base IMessage interface its in a 3rd party lib. So what would be better a

Write a Wrapper , this works with Json .net where it uses Known Type on the member lookups. 
eg

```
[ProtoContract(1)]
[ProtoInclude (1, typeof(Message1))]] 
public class MessageHolder
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public IMessage {get; set;}  // eg Message1 : IMessage
}
```

Or do I get the byte[] , manually put in my own code in the first few bytes lookup the type and manually dispatch using the remaining bytes ?

Comment: Just my spontaneous thought, use Wrapper. To get better control and clearer use.

Comment: MessageHolder is a Wrapper of am I missing another Wrapper.  This post uses a wrapper as well but still marks the base interface  which I cannot do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182188/interfaces-with-protobuf-net-and-c-sharp?rq=1.