unexpected sub-type for interface
I have an interface, and I can serialize a class that has that as a member.
Ie, this works:
    static void testSerializeInterface()
    {
        var ai = new anImplemntation();
        ai.aVal = 101;
        var tp = new testParent();
        tp.aTest = ai;
        MemoryStream msTEMP = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(msTEMP, ai);

    }

    interface iTest
    {
        void Go();
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class anImplemntation:iTest
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)] public int aVal;
        public void Go() { }
    }



    [ProtoContract]
    class testParent
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)] public iTest aTest;
    }

However my actual data structure is complex, containing lots of Dictionary and List of objects, and if I try to serialize that I get an error saying "unexpected sub-type anImplmentation", even though "anImplementation" does serialize as demonstrated.
How do I fix?
@Fildor below is a minimal reproducible example.
It actually produces a different error in this instance ("No serializer or type iTest is available to model (default)") but I think it shows a problem:
       public static void testSerializeInterface()
    {
        var ai = new anImplemntation();
        var tp = new testParent();
        tp.aTest = ai;
        ai.aList.Add(new anImplemntation());
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, ai);
    }

    interface iTest
    {
        void Go();
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class anImplemntation : iTest
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)] public int aVal;
        [ProtoMember(2)] public List<iTest> aList = new List<iTest>();
        public void Go() { }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class testParent
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)] public iTest aTest;
    }


Try and create an [mre]. Not only to post it here, but it may already show you where the problem is. With the information given, it will be hard to tell anything that's better than a guess.

If you want to serialize interfaces you probably want to take a look at How to Serialize Inherited Class with ProtoBuf-Net.

@JonasH Interfaces are different to Inherited classes surely?
According to Marc Gravell's (who definitely knows what he is talking about) answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182188/interfaces-with-protobuf-net-and-c-sharp, interfaces should be straightforward

When deserializing the library needs to know what concrete type to deserialize to. That what ProtoInclude is for. System.Text.Json uses a similar attribute based approach. I might be missunderstanding the question, but I would ceirtanly start by trying to add a ProtoContract as well as ProtoInclude to the interface, exactly as is done in the question you linked.

@JonasH if I add [ProtoContract] to iTest I get "unexpected sub-type", if I also add ProtoInclude(1000,typeof(anImplemntation)) to iTest I get "the type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated for anImplementation"

well, I'm out of ideas. It seem to work fine if using a abstract class instead an interface. This issue has some discussions about problems with interfaces. Maybe Its a problem with recursive type definition? I would probably consider using separate classes for serialization, so they can be adapted for quirks in the serialization library.
